# Android HDMI dual display using allwinner A20

Tags: linux-kernel, android-4.2-jelly-bean, toolchain

we developed out custom android for our own board developed by our company. Initially I am having issues in displaying similar content on hdmi but i solved that issue . Now we are trying to display different content on hdmi but

/sys/devices/virtual/disp/disp/hdmi status is showing 0  (HDMI not Connected !)

while we are having similar display on hdmi port. We are using android 4.2. I need guidance, where to look in the android code or do i have to change my driver for hdmi ( because i am using driver for marsboard A20) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to see in product fex file that whether HDMI support is enable in your device or not.

You will find product fex file in lichee/tools/pack/chips/sun7i/config/android//sys_config.fex.

Check values of screen0_output_type and screen1_output_type attributes.

Comment: sys_config.fex is all set for dual display in my case. I found my issue there is no code written in display.cpp class and we have write the code for that, anyways thanks for you help and guidance.